# Django Generic views not working for PUT , GET , UPDATE , PATCH

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have   `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`  view like this.

```
class TaskRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = TasksSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set=Task.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and my urls like this

```
 path('task_detail/<int:id>', TaskRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.as_view(), name="get_task"),
```

I am trying to PUT , PATCH  , GET  but getting same error

```
{
    "detail": "Not found.",
    "status_code": 404
}
```

Comment: Give examples of the requests you're making

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the function `get_queryset`, It expects a queryset but yours returns a single object, that's what the `get` function does as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get). So, you need to either set the `queryset` class field or use the `get_queryset` function.

You don't need to look up the task object yourself, that's what the generic view does for you. also you don't have to specify the method handlers(`get`, `post`, i.e.) yourself, they are already generated because you use `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` class. Also, since the lookup field defaults to the primary key(id), so, you could omit that, too

Try this code

```
class TaskRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TasksSerializer
```

and use `pk` instead of `id`

```
 path('task_detail/<int:pk>', TaskRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView.as_view(), name="get_task")
```

or you could leave the lookup field as `id` and use it in the `path` function. It's pretty much the same thing, just saving some code